# GridView Calculated Field

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I can create a custom link in my ASPX page like this:

```
<asp:GridView 

    ID="GridView1" 
    CssClass="rounded-corner" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    EnableModelValidation="True" 
    AllowSorting="True"
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" 
    EnableViewState="true"
    AllowPaging="True"   
    PageSize="10"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" >

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE_ENTERED" HeaderText="Date Submitted" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM" HeaderText="Your Claim #" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PRIMARY_INSURED" HeaderText="Insured" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PRIMARY_CLAIMANT" HeaderText="Claimant" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LOB_ID" HeaderText="Type" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:HyperLink ID="BRANCH_NAME" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "mailto:"+Eval("OWNERS_EMAIL") %>' Text='<%# Eval("BRANCH_NAME") %>' ToolTip='<%# 
                   "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">"+Eval("BRANCH_NAME").ToString().Trim() + "</span><br />" + 
                   Eval("OWNERS_FIRST_NAME").ToString().Trim() + " " +
                   Eval("OWNERS_LAST_NAME").ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
                   Eval("OWNERS_EMAIL").ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
                   Eval("OWNERS_OFFICE_PHONE").ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
                   Eval("OWNERS_FAX_PHONE").ToString().Trim()
                   %> '> 
                   </asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Is there, instead, a way to do this directly in my code behind; by creating a type of "calculated field?"

The code behind is as follows:

```
DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
using ( IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection() )
{
    string sSQL;
    // 12/04/2006 Paul.  Only include active users. 
    sSQL = "select top 20                "         + ControlChars.CrLf
         + " DATE_ENTERED, CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM, PRIMARY_INSURED, PRIMARY_CLAIMANT, LOB_ID, BRANCH_NAME," + ControlChars.CrLf
         + " OWNERS_FIRST_NAME, OWNERS_LAST_NAME, OWNERS_NAME, OWNERS_EMAIL, OWNERS_OFFICE_PHONE, OWNERS_FAX_PHONE" + ControlChars.CrLf
         + "  from vwFILES_DetailViewWithOwners" + ControlChars.CrLf
         + " where 1 = 1                   " + ControlChars.CrLf;
    using ( IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL;

        using ( DbDataAdapter da = dbf.CreateDataAdapter() )
        {
            ((IDbDataAdapter)da).SelectCommand = cmd;
            using ( DataTable dt = new DataTable() )
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                vwMain = dt.DefaultView;
                GridView1.DataSource = vwMain;
                if ( !IsPostBack )
                {

                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I simply create the new field in my code behind so I can call it like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="BRANCH_NAME" 
            runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl='<%# "mailto:"+Eval("OWNERS_EMAIL") %>' 
            Text='<%# Eval("BRANCH_NAME") %>' 
            ToolTip='<%# Eval("MY_CALCULATED_FIELD") %>'> 
       </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function in your C# code to format the data.  This article on MSDN talks about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx#aspnett12ustmpfldsvb_topic5

To summarize, you would change your item template like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="BRANCH_NAME" runat="server" 
          NavigateUrl='<%# "mailto:"+Eval("OWNERS_EMAIL") %>' 
          Text='<%# Eval("BRANCH_NAME") %>' 
          ToolTip='<%# GetBranchAddress(CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row) %> '> 
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and in your c#, create a function like this:

```
protected string GetBranchAddress(DataRow row)
{
    return "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">"+ 
               row["BRANCH_NAME"].ToString().Trim() + "</span><br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_FIRST_NAME"].ToString().Trim() + " " +
               row["OWNERS_LAST_NAME"].ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_EMAIL"].ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_OFFICE_PHONE"].ToString().Trim() + "<br />" + 
               row["OWNERS_FAX_PHONE"].ToString().Trim();

}
```

This approach is also nice because you can set breakpoints in the c# function and add error handling, etc.

Comment: I tried this today and I get the error, "No overload for method 'GetBranchAddress' takes '0' arguments."  How can I pass the variable `row` to the function?

Comment: You are right.  In my example, I forgot to show how to pass the argument to the function.  I updated the example (for ItemTemplate) to show how to pass the Row as an argument to the function.  Btw, in the linked page (on MSDN), it talks about this in the paragraph below "Figure 15".